# Bidets aren't really a thing in Western Europe. What can I do as a traveler?

Tags: international-travel, hygiene

In my home country, using a [bidet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet) or a [bidet spray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet_shower) is the de facto method to clean yourself after a number two. Many people go for the water-then-paper method, and I'm one of those people. Currently, I live in Finland where bidet sprays are relatively common in households and female bathrooms in bars and restaurants. I'm also lucky to have one in my apartment.

Whenever I travel to a different city or a different country, I end up in the uncomfortable situation where I have to clean using paper only. After that, I spend the whole day worrying about it, and it just feels so damn uncomfortable.

Wet wipes don't cut it, pouring water from bottle is just not as clean, and planning my hotel reservations around that problem is too impractical.

**Is there any solution for this?** Something like an improvised DIY water jet thing, even a commercial solution would be fine.